# Is there a similar approach as Postgres's ts_vector field for ElasticSearch?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, tsvector

When using Postgres you can index a string in a database field as a vector using ts_vector. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSVECTOR)

Is there a similar concept for ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much what ES does under the hood when you index a string into a `text` field.

Let's take the first example from the link you provided: `a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat rat`

With the PG `tsvector` type, the following tokens are going to be analyzed and indexed

```
a and ate cat fat mat on rat sat
```

If you want to keep positions, you need to specify them, like this:

```
a:1 fat:2 cat:3 sat:4 on:5 a:6 mat:7 and:8 ate:9 a:10 fat:11 rat:12
```

Whereas with ES, positions are kept automatically without having to specify them. It is also possible to tell ES to not record them (to save space)

With the ES `text` type and the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), the following tokens are going to be analyzed and indexed

```
a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat rat
```

With the [`english` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer), we get this (stopwords removed, words stemming, etc)

```
fat cat sat mat at fat rat
```

ES doesn't store the tokens alphabetically, it doesn't really help either with free-text search. Also it doesn't remove duplicates (although it is [possible to do it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-remove-duplicates-tokenfilter.html)) because that interferes with the token frequency in the document and in the index, hence the scoring.

Basically, both do index pretty much the same tokens, although ES is a search engine at heart and does it in a much more optimal way. When looking at the `tsquery` type, free text searches in ES are also a bit more user-friendly.

Comment: Not commenting on your opinions, I have to remark that `to_tsvector` *does* collect the word position automatically, and you don't have to specify them. I guess your judgement is not based on intimate knowledge of PostgreSQL full text search.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for adding your 2 cents regarding `to_tsvector`. PS: I'm not sure where you detected a "judgment" in my answer, I just tried to make a side-by-side comparison. Facts are that ES is not a database (like Postgres is) and Postgres is not a search engine (like ES is), so without a concrete use case on which to evaluate both technologies, we're just comparing apples and oranges anyway ;-)

Comment: I was referring to "user-friendly" and "more optimal". But I agree that a text search engine and a database are different, and I would expect Elasticsearch as a dedicated full text search engine to offer some benefits.

Comment: yes, that was a bit opinionated, indeed. "user-friendly" is subjective but "more optimal" is pretty objective when you come to think of how ES allows you to customize the analysis process, I'm not sure Postgres offers the same possibilities.

Comment: @Val Thank you for your response. This definitely helps me understand better and leads me to what I think my actual question should have been. Which is, what is the ElasticSearch equivalent of a Postgres query which searches a ts_vector field using `@@ to_tsquery(:searchQuery)`